# Driver needed during windows installation

Tags: windows-7, drivers, ssd

I just lately bought an Lenovo T560 and replaced the ssd with an samsung 850 pro ssd 512gb.

Now I am trying to install windows 7 on it via usb and it works until I come to the partition part. My Laptop can't find the ssd and asks for a driver.

I was looking for a driver the last couple of hours but I could not find one.

All I know is I need a SATA driver and it cannot be an exe.

I don't know what I should look for and hope that someone here has experience.

If there is something unclear ask.

Comment: SATA drivers are built into Windows 7.  Lenovo places all required drivers for your laptop on their website.

Comment: That is weird, and pretty much should not happen. Is Win7 image you used legit or modified? Have you checked new disk in other machine>

Comment: The Win7image should work perfectly the only thing I modified was letting the intel usb 3.0 utility fly over it . @Ramhound Yes Lenovo places a lot of drivers and often the required ones but all downloads on the Lenovo site are exes which I can't put on the Laptop because I am in the middle of the windows installation.

Comment: You download the drivers, install them, then extract the .inf files.  You then have to add the drivers to the installation image.  How you do that is well documented.  Of course none of that should be required, since Windows 7 has the required SATA drivers, built into the image.

Comment: Well, I installed some drivers on an other pc and put the driver files on a usb to install it on my laptop. I could install some drivers but not a fitting one. If you belive that strong in Windows 7 having all the sata drivers what other problem could it be? Because in the last three hours all I read about this problem were missing drivers

Comment: I presume that this SSD you have is a SATA III drive and not a PCI-E drive?  You would indeed need to supply the NVMHCI drivers if it was PCI-E

Comment: Are you completely sure it is physically connected? I have had the same issue on a similar Lenovo system, and it turned out somehow I had managed to put the cover back on without securing the hard drive in properly.

Comment: I tried to installe some other drivers but unfortunately nothing worked. So I opened the laptop again and checked the SSD, it was correctly connected. The only thing I could do was removing the SSD, connecting it to another similar laptop via usb, clone the SSD and put it back in my laptop with windowqs already installed.